# Pushy recruiter demanding screenshot of me

Tags: recruitment

I got a call from a pushy recruiter today and she did not stop calling my phone which is weird, usually they just leave a message and thats it. I looked up online, and the company seems to be above board, but the recruiter is pushy, wanting to know the month and day of my birthday, the full name as listed on my social and lastly a screenshot. It just sounds like she is completing enough information to develop a fake id to sell to someone.

Does it sound above board for a recruiter to demand a screenshot of me to present to a customer?

Or was I being phished? If I was being social engineered for a phishing expedition for identity theft. What can I do about it?

This person even has a LinkedIn page with a history of being a recruiter, so its really hard to tell (but no profile picture of her).

I hung up on her after being pushy about different ways to get a screenshot of me after I provided pushback for the first way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104998/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-pushy-recruiter-demanding-screenshot-of-me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can I do about it?

This also sounds fishy to me.

I would not answer any other of her calls if she is being that insistent and pushy.

As suggested in comments by Paul, you may want to inform the recruitment company about this incident so they are also aware of this and so the nature of this situation is clearer to you (perhaps this is a legit, but pushy, recruiter?).

---

*Edit:* Seems that you called them and they confirmed this is a legit recruiter, and the unusual information they ask is because of client requirement.

In this case, you should decide if you are comfortable with providing such information and things, so you can proceed with the application or not, and continue looking for other options.

Comment: Any recruiter asking for those details is not legit. Birthday is not something you are even legally allowed to ask about in some countries/states. Not to mention that it doesn't matter for hiring.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, I contacted their offices and the guy confirmed the recruiter saying that he is aware that this is a lot to ask up front, but its not them, its the customer that is asking for this, the customer is a bank that is a household name for most of us and its because in the past a recruiter submitted for someone and then it ended up being their cousin that shows up to the interview. Thats their rationale.

Comment: I agree with that. What I'm saying is that by telling the recruitment company OP can do both inform them and get a clearer view of this situation, by perhaps getting feedback from the company after informing. Just to be completely sure

Comment: @Daniel so, they confirmed this is legit then... well, then you should decide if you are comfortable or not with providing such information and things, so you can proceed with the application or decline it.

Comment: @DarkCygnus, thanks. I am honestly not comfortable with that. This customer, again a bank we all know, should know better than to require a recruitment company to ask such information, just based on the fact that its a U.S. based company and they should be aware of our nuances here. If it were a Latin-American company, then sure, they are accustomed to asking for photos with a resume, I think in Europe too, but its a huge U.S. bank, they should know better, my cousin showing up or not to the interview is irrelevant. Anyway, thats my opinion.

Comment: I am stunned to say the least.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to pin this on the actual client. For all we know, the line about the client requirement and the cousin is just excuse-making on the recruiter's part because they're trying to weasel information out of you so they can make your resume look flashy.

Comment: @Daniel I worked for a US bank in the past and can confirm that these questions from the recruiter are completely unreasonable. I cannot imagine any legit recruiter asking these questions from you in the US (even if they claim they're legit). This sounds a lot like a scam to me. I would refuse to work with this recruiter (the company and the individual) in the future.

Comment: @xxbbcc, thank you for your comment. This is helpful.

Comment: A bank, bank! that doesn't know how to do background checks? Really? Even if the bank is well-established, it sounds like this office has bizarre employment  practices. And, a recruiter making unusual demands of candidates without explaining why and trying to be persuasive? Also strange. Strange enough to walk away.